# How to handle the 400 response from youtube gdata "response"?

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

I have app that allows users to fill a form containing a youtube link. Many a times, the video link is invalid and I'd have to fix it manually. I want to validate the url before I allow user to submit the form.

I'm wrote some code on the firebug console:

```
function test() {
//    var x1 = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OvcaXrWFM2Q";
    var x1 = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?alt";
    var asd = false;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        url: x1, 
/*        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success --> ", data.length);
            return true;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error --> ", error);
        },
*/        complete: function(e){
            console.log("complete --> ", e);
            return true;
        }
    });

//    return false ;
    return asd;
}


var y = test();

if (y) {
    console.log("success y --> " + y);
} else {
    console.log("error y --> " + y);
}
```

Invalid 400 request:

```
>>> function test() { //    var x1 = "http://gdata.y...} else {     console.log("error y --> " + y); } 

error y --> false
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?alt&callback=jsonp1375741532312&_=1375800027900"
```

Valid response:

```
>>> function test() {     var x1 = "http://gdata.you...} else {     console.log("error y --> " + y); } 

error y --> false
success --> 4516
jquery....min.js (line 29)
complete --> undefined
jquery....min.js (line 29)
```

What can I do to catch that 400? Also, it seems the code gets to "console.log("success y --> " + y);" before it gets to the success: function().

Edit:

My other option is to send this validation to backend using java, but I'd prefer it using js.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] urls = new String[2];
        urls[0] = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OvcaXrWFM2Q";
        urls[1] = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/23487978923789423789342sufyu";
        HttpURLConnection con;
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output I get as expected, 200 for valid video id, 400 for the invalid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the response status code, I had to move the check to backend java. Javascript just couldn't do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] urls = new String[2];
        urls[0] = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OvcaXrWFM2Q";
        urls[1] = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/23487978923789423789342sufyu";
        HttpURLConnection con;
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```